Generalized Coons patch?
A Coons patch is a common parametric surface often taught in computer graphics courses.
The gist of it is, given $4$ curves, one can create opposite facing pairs of them, create two ruled surfaces, then create a bilinear patch and finally blend all three together to create a final surface.
Assume now that you have $k \geq 3$ curves, which are non-self intersecting and meet at their endpoints, i.e. their union is topologically equivalent to a polygon with $k$ sides.
Is there a way to define a parametric surface, such that its boundary is exactly these curves and such that it is equal to the Coons patch for the case where $k=4$?

I was going to say that's  an unfortunate name considering the racial connotations tied to that "c" word, until I realized it was meant to be the name of a person

@NickAlger That paper is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

@Nick Alger My anti-virus says the link you have given for the Peter Salvi paper isn't secure. Here is one which is secure.

@JeanMarie Ok, deleting the old comment. Here it is without the link. This question seems to be the topic of the following paper: Peter Salvi, "Multi-sided generalizations of the Coons patch". As an aside, if you are interested in 3D or higher dimension generalization but still on a box, you can do that using the inclusion/exclusion principle. I.e., sum all linear interpolations of opposing faces, subtract all bilinear interpolations of parallel edges, add back the trilinear interpolation of the vertices.
